# Why does this loop more than once when a letters are entered?

Tags: c++, input

Why is it that when the user enters more than one letter the console displays "how long is the road in meters " and "Please enter an Integer which is between 0 and 250." more than once

For example if I enter "abc" the console will display this:

how long is the road in meters

abc

Please enter an Integer which is between 0 and 250.
how long is the road in meters

Please enter an Integer which is between 0 and 250.
how long is the road in meters

Please enter an Integer which is between 0 and 250.
how long is the road in meters

```
while (!valid)
    {
        cout << "how long is the road in meters " << endl;
        cin >> road;
        valid = true; 
        if ((cin.fail()) || ((road > 250) || (road < 0)))
        {
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(); 
            cout << "Please enter an Integer which is between 0 and 250." << endl;
            valid = false; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin.ignore();` is equivalent to `cin.ignore(1,EOF);`
So you skipped only 1 character, but there are 3 in the cin buffer.
You should call

`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` instead to clear the whole buffer

Edited according to @mszymborski's comment.

Edit 2: added `std::`, and note that the usage of std::numeric_limits requires `#include <limits>`

Comment: `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` would be a better bet than a weird constant like `1000`. Just because it's not a larger program doeesn't mean we shouldn't write it decently.

Comment: Yes, that would be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The fail state is triggered at char 'a' from the entry "abc".  You then clear the error ignore this char and loop.  The next available char in the input stream is then b, and so on.

If you want to handle the input as a whole, you could read a string (or a full line) and parse the string using a `stringstream`:

```
    getline(cin, line);  
    stringstream sst(line); 
    sst>>road; 
    if ((sst.fail()....) 
       ...
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/pAJs5C)